# python conditional subtraction of a column from a constant

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have a Dataframe for instance:

```
df <- data.frame("condition" = [a,a,a,b,b,b,a,b], "dv1" = [7,8,6,3,2,1,5,4])`
```

and I want to subtract 10 from column dv1 only if values in column condition equals to "a". Is there a way in python to do so such as using def and if function? I have tried the following but doesn't work:

```
def recode():
    for i in df["condition']:
        if i == "a":
    return abs(10-df["dv1"])
```

Comment: Are you facing any error?

Comment: Your first line of code looks like R not Python

Comment: @James sorry if it's confusing. I'm still learning how to post codes and Dataframe on stack. I am using python, just that in python the Dataframe was imported.

Comment: @Vaibhav Jadhav python gives an error message "IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Comment: @Amelia check the below solution

Answer (score 0):

Indent the code like this:

```
def recode():
    for i in df["condition"]:
        if i == "a":
            return abs(10-df["dv1"])
```

Comment: Thanks! but it says :for i in df["consequential']:
                                 ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Can you show that code which contains this function?

Comment: `def recode():`
    `for i in df["condition']:`
        `if i == "a":`
            `return abs(10-df["dv1"])`
                
`df_clean = df['dv1'].apply(recode)`

Comment: condition is opened with a double quote, but closed by a single quote.